# Any known identity that gives this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, reference-request

Let $\boldsymbol{v} = (v_1,v_2\ldots v_n)$ where $v_i \in \mathbb{R}$

show that there exists a $K>0$ such that $$ \left|\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\right|^2 \le K\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2  $$

I'd like to know any known identity that gives this result directly?

**What I know**

$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\right|^2 \le \left|\sum_{i=1}^n|v_i|\right|^2 = \|\boldsymbol{v}\|^2_1$$

and as $1$-norm is equivalent to $2$-norm (equivalence of norms) we have that there exists a $K>0$ such that $\|\boldsymbol{v}\|^2_1\le K\|\boldsymbol{v}\|^2_2$ and the result follows.

But I dont want to take this approach in my write up and I want a crisp statement by citing a standard and well known inequality if it exists. Appreciate any reference as well.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $v=(v_1,...,v_n)^T$ and $w=(1,...,1)^T$.

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\left|\sum_{i=1}^nv_i\right|^2 = \left |\langle  w,v\rangle\right|^2 \leq \|w\|^2\|v\|^2= \left(\sum_{j=1}^n1 \right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2\right)=n\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: $\sum_{j=1}^n 1 = n$, not $=n^2$. This gives a sharper inequality and $v_1=v_2=\ldots v_n=1$ shows that $K=n$ is best possible.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo.